# Ruby regex need to exclude pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

I have the following strings

```
ALEXANDRITE OVAL 5.1x7.9 GIA# 6167482443 FINE w:1.16
ALEXANDRITE OVAL 4x6 FINE w:1.16
```

I want to match the 5.1 and 7.9 and the 4 and 6 and not  w:1.16 or w: 1.16 or the 6167482443. So far I managed to come up with these:

Matching the w:1.16 w: 1.16

```
([w][:]\d\.?\d*|[w][:]\s?\d\.?\d*)
```

Matching the other digits:

```
\d+\.?\d{,3}
```

I kind of expected this not the return the long number sequence because of the {,3} but it still does.

My questions are : 
1. How do I combine the two patterns excluding one and returning the other?
2. How do I exclude the long sequence of numbers? Why is it not being excluded now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the below regex.

```
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/krL7rF5TRH)

**Explanation:**

```
\b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                         something that is not a word char
(                        group and capture to \1:
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional):
    \.                       '.'
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  )?                       end of grouping
)                        end of \1
x                        'x'
(                        group and capture to \2:
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional):
    \.                       '.'
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  )?                       end of grouping
)                        end of \2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
([\d\.])+x([\d\.])+
```

matches

```
5.1x7.9

4x6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=x)|(?<=x)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/6

2)To ignore the long string you have to use `\b\d{1,3}\b` to specify boundaries.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/7

Or else a part of long string will match.